# Rectángulos desaparecen al colisionar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Hola estoy haciendo un juego de un laberinto y necesito hacer colisiones entre el jugador y los bordes del laberinto. Lo que pasa es que al colisionar los rectángulos desaparecen. Podrian decirme que pasa?. Gracias de antemano.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint

ancho = 700
alto = 640

negro = (0,0,0)
blanco = (255,255,255)

class Stanly(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/Stanly.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 50
        self.rect.centery = 580

        self.vel = 1

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.y += self.vel
        if self.rect.bottom > 640:
            self.rect.bottom = 640

        if keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.y -= self.vel
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0

        if keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += self.vel
        if self.rect.right > 700:
            self.rect.right = 700

        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= self.vel
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

class rectU(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/ud.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 0
        self.rect.top = 0

class rectD(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/ud.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 0
        self.rect.top = 608

class rectL(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/lr.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 0
        self.rect.top = 0
class rectR(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/lr.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.right = 700
        self.rect.top = 0


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
rects = pygame.sprite.Group()
Mrects = pygame.sprite.Group()
players = pygame.sprite.Group()


def Game():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1,25)

    ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((ancho, alto))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

    player = Stanly()

    RectU = rectU()
    RectD = rectD()
    RectL = rectL()
    RectR = rectR()

    all_sprites.add(player)
    all_sprites.add(RectU)
    all_sprites.add(RectD)
    all_sprites.add(RectL)
    all_sprites.add(RectR)


    rects.add(RectU)
    rects.add(RectD)
    rects.add(RectL)
    rects.add(RectR)

    players.add(player)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()



        colls = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(players, rects, False, True)
        for player, rects_ in colls.items():
            player.rect.centerx = 50
            player.rect.centery = 580

        # Actualizamos todos los sprites del juego
        all_sprites.update()
        ventana.fill(negro)
        # Dibujamos todos los sprites     
        all_sprites.draw(ventana)
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

Game()
```

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionar un enlace a los png que usa tu juego? (por ejemplo, subirlos a [imgur](https://imgur.com/), o pegarlos como parte de la pregunta). De este modo podríamos probar a ejecutarlo para ver qué va mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la línea:

```
colls = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(players, rects, False, True)
```

El método [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) recibe los siguientes argumentos:

```
groupcollide(group1, group2, dokill1, dokill2, collided = None)
```

Como tiene el argumento `dokill2` como `True` los sprites del grupo `rects` son automáticamente "asesinados" cuando se produce una colisión con los del primer grupo. Es decir, son removidos del grupo de forma automática cuando colisionan.

Simplemente haz :

```
colls = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(players, rects, False, False)
```

Comment: Como siempre Sevilla salva el día.